# IP address -> simple word hash table function in PHP

Tags: php, hash, hashmap, hashtable, ip-address

I have a client's IP address and an array full of simple words. Let's say...

```
$ip_addr = ip2long('172.16.254.12'); //returns an integer
```

and

```
$words = array('cat', 'dog', 'nest', 'barn', 'etc'); //arbitrary length
```

I'm trying to figure out a clever way to map the ip address to a position in the array consistently so `172.16.254.12` always turns into `cat` etc. and that another IP would turn into say, `dog`. Ideally this process would not be easily reversible so as to obscure the client's IP address and there should not be too many collisions (but collisions not so important). I know this needs a hash table, but not entirely sure how to implement it. Don't need to worry about ipv6 for right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hashing function required:

```
$ip_addr = ip2long('172.16.254.12'); //returns an integer
$words = array('cat', 'dog', 'nest', 'barn', 'etc'); //arbitrary length

$chosen_word = $words[$ip_addr % count($words)];
```